# Injecting service into controller throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am unable to inject service into controller. I was able to execute a similar code a year ago and it worked but this time I am having a hard luck.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('product', [
  "ngRoute",
]);
```

**main.ctrl.js**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$http','srv', function ($scope,$http,srv) {
    var srvUrl = srv.getSrvUrl;
    var data = srv.getData(1,2);
}]);
```

**srv.js**

```
app.service("srv", function ($http,$scope) {
    this.getSrvUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/api/";
    this.getData = function(a,b) { return a*b; }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!--JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--APP-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
<!-- ROUTE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/routes/app.route.js"></script>
<!-- SERVICE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/services/srv.js"></script>
<!--CONTROLLER-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/main.ctrl.js"></script>
```

**console error**

```
angular.js:14362 
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20srv
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4650
at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4803)
at angular.js:4655
at d (angular.js:4803)
at e (angular.js:4828)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4874)
at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:4712)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4862)
at Object.$get (angular.js:4696)
```

Please help.

Comment: I think you can't inject $scope in a service. try removing that

Comment: yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not inject `$scope` in service.

Service are singleton object used to share data and some reusable methods.

It should be like this

```
app.service("srv", function ($http, $scope) {
    return {
        getSrvUrl: "http://127.0.0.1/api/",
        getData: function (a, b) { return a * b; }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only scope you can inject in a service is `$rootScope` (but given your code, I'm not sure you need a scope at all in the service). Also, you'll probably want to add the service names as strings for minification:

```
app.service("srv", ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    // ...
}]);
```